# How do I permanently block a Telegram user? The user should not be unblocked even after the user deletes and recreate their account. Is there any way?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, social-media

I am trying to block a telegram number permanently but when the user deletes his account and reopens his account, He is still able to send me messages from his account.

```
1. Is there a way to block him permanently?
2. if yes, How to block him permanently?
3. Is there any bot that can help?
```

I know it is possible because, One of my contacts blocked me once but when I tried deleting and recreating the account, I am still blocked and not able to text that contact. Note: My phone number privacy in telegram is "Nobody" and The user doesn't have my number.

```
4. How they blocked me permanently?
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this programmatically or using telegram application ?

Comment: Both is fine. May be by using bot or just using application.

Comment: Actually, Someone blocked me like this permanently. They don't have my mobile number but still when I deleted and recreated my account the block existed. I searched many places to find how they did it but I can't find the answer. I am very curious what method they used to do so or is there any chance/hack of my mobile number revealed to them? when My mobile number privacy is "Nobody".

Comment: Make sure that 'someone' account really exists. Try to send message from different accounts. Because telegram block works based on `id` and not on `MobileNumber`.

Comment: Yes, Their account really exists. I am able to send messages from other accounts but not from my account even when I deleted and recreated my account. If telegram blocks using `ID`, Will the ID be unique even after deleting and recreating the account? Or Is there any Way/Bot/Hack to detect ID change?

Comment: Telegram ID regenerated when you delete and recreate account.

Comment: Is there any way to detect the `Regenerated ID` change or are The old `ID` and `Regenerated ID` are same?. If not, How the block still exists? or Is there any possibility my mobile number was revealed?

Comment: Is that account bot? Have you ever shared your mobile number with them? Telegram is not providing mobile number in API. Not sure why and How the block still exists.

Comment: That account doesn't seem to be a bot because it has no username, If I am not wrong all bots will have a username that ends with `Bot`.  I have never shared my mobile number with them.

Comment: But that user once said that he is using a different(Unofficial) version of telegram. I also tried many versions but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236490/discussion-between-vinayak-and-harshad-raval).